# Jquery call back into same view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I have a certain list,

```
List<string> searchList = new List<string>();
searchList.Add("Annotation Text");
searchList.Add("Basic Search");
searchList.Add("Comments");
```

I have a text box, 'Add search type' button, a 'select' option and one main 'search Claims' button as shown below

```
<div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter search type" id="enteredSearchType" />
     <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btnNormal" id="searchType">Add Search Type</button>
     </span>
</div>
<div class="multiselect">
     <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
          <select>
             <option>Select an option</option>
          </select>
          <div class="overSelect"></div>
     </div>
     <div id="checkboxes">
          @foreach (var searchType in searchList)
          {
              if (searchType.Contains())
              {
                 <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" id="one"/>@searchType</label>
              }
          }                                       
      </div>
</div>   
<button class="btn btnNormal" id="searchClaims">Search Claims</button>
```

What I type in my text box and click 'Add Search Type' I want the value to be checked in the list if the list contains the value I want it to be added to select option..

My current jquery is below,

```
$("#searchType").on("click", function () {
        var searchValue = $("#enteredSearchType").val();


    });
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you mockup a JSFiddle with just the output HTML (e.g. saved from the browser after running the page)? You have some very odd things going on in your Razor code that I do not yet understand.

Comment: For starters you are creating duplicate `id="one"` which is invalid HTML. jQuery/Javascript can only see the first match with IDs

Comment: But its a list of checkboxes in select, how can i change that?..Its in foreach loop..

Comment: If you post your output HTML, so I can understand your question better, I can then suggest a better way to do this using Razor. The problem is, to me, this makes no sense at the moment. :)

Comment: I don't get why someone would type something in a textbox to check a checkbox seems a bit convoluted and not a very good user experience.

Comment: @Pete- The list I have shown containing 3 values was an example..It has upto 100 values which need to be in select option as checkboxes..I don't want so many, So I type a value in text box and click 'Add Search type' if the value is present in my list..Then add only that value as checkbox in select list, and not unnecessarily add the complete list as checkboxes in select list..

Comment: Any chance of that output HTML? Otherwise it's *vote-to-close* and *move on*. Sorry.

Comment: @True:- Isn't my view my output html...The one I've posted is my view...

Comment: That is view *source* and requires compiling (if only mentally). For jQuery mockups (and figuring out your UI) just save the output HTML from the running page (use the F12 Chrome DOM inspector and paste it to a JSFiddle).

Comment: If you have hundreds of checkboxes I wouldn't bother with the submit button - I would just start filtering the checkboxes as the user types in the box so that they are presented with any matching checkboxes so they can just check it.  The way you do it requires the user to exactly match the search term which they may not know to start with (unless you are using an autocomplete plugin)

Comment: @Pete-That is why I was trying to use 'if (searchType.Contains())' within foreach but didn't know how to proceed as the Jquery somehow should get the entered value from text box and come back so I can use it in 'if (searchType.Contains())'...And once I confirm that it does contain the value i want to add it to 'select' option.

Comment: @True- I'm working on JSFiddle...

Comment: @True- My JSFiddle isn't looking that great, but I hope it shows you what my problem is... https://jsfiddle.net/s81g7zdm/     https://jsfiddle.net/s81g7zdm/embedded/result/

Comment: One last time: **Do not use the source code for a JSFiddle**. It has no idea how to compile Razor views. Use the *output* HTML from your browser. e.g. 1. Run your website. 2. Open the DOM inspector. 3. Copy the HTML of the body element into your JSFiddle. 4. Press Update. 5. Let us know :)